Over a month and a half has gone since the status changed to "Decision in Process"
On June 7, 2024, I submitted my paper to a reputable journal. After a day, it was in the status "With Editor". The status was changed to "Under review" after a few days. The status was updated to "Decision in process" on August 6. Up until then, nothing has changed. How should I proceed?

Still now, my article is in "Decision in process" status. It is 133 days now. What should I do?
